# how can we track user activity?

Tags: users, user-management

Is there a way to track the applications a user uses, while they are logged in?
Our company is experimenting with laptops whose use is for going to conferences, and business trips. We are in the process of hardening these laptops as much as possible, while still maintaining usability. So, we would like to track what applications are in use, most frequently.

I can guess, its libre office, and Firefox, but having details would be amazing.

Comment: As far as GUI apps go, i have an idea, but console - only bash history.... unless they use another shell

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple software tools to do this in a GUI:

- [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com) [Paid]
  Allows tracking of user activity, what apps they're using, etc.
- [arbtt](http://freecode.com/projects/arbtt) [Free]
  Allows tracking of what applications are open and for how long. Most similar to RescueTime, but free.

For the commandline, you can track `.bash_history` and record all the commands executed.

---

However, you must ***trust your users.*** Anything you install can (pretty easily) be disabled by the end-users to hide their true activity and time.