# Suggest any GUI App similar to digital wellbeing or Qualitytime for Ubuntu

Tags: time, system-monitor, focus, organizer, time-management

I am new to Ubuntu. I want to count the total time spend on each app and on-screen time. Is there a software for the same?

For example Digital Wellbeing and QualityTime.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465016/how-do-i-get-the-active-window-on-gnome-wayland

Answer (score 2):

The examples you give
([Digital Wellbeing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.wellbeing)
and [QualityTime](https://www.qualitytimeapp.com/))
are both Android applications,
but note that commercial applications also often have Linux clients as well.
The issue is that automatic application time-tracking
is a form of surveillance,
and in some sense a form of spyware.
An application that sends this information to a server somewhere
is a greater privacy risk than an application that stores it locally.
One of the issues with commercial applications
is that they are generally closed-source,
and therefore it's hard to verify what data they are collecting
and where they are sending it.
Therefore, I will list only open source options below.
(Note that even open source applications like this deserve scrutiny;
see [this Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=873955)
for more.)

[In the Ubuntu package manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/arbtt),
there is arbtt:

> arbtt is a background daemon that stores which windows are open, which one
> has the focus and how long since your last action (and possbly more sources
> later), and stores this. It is also a program that will, based on expressive
> rules you specify, derive what you were doing, and what for.
>
> The documentation, which includes the changelog, can also be found at
> http://arbtt.nomeata.de/doc/users_guide/.
>
> WARNING: The log file might contain very sensitive private data. Make sure
> you understand the consequences of a full-time logger and be careful with
> this data.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arbtt

This is a very powerful option,
but you will need to set up the configuration file
and reports yourself,
which may be somewhat time consuming to customize to your needs.

Other open-source options:

- https://github.com/karpathy/ulogme

  > ulogme is small and simple: There are two *backend* components: a tracking
  > script that records activity and a small local web server wrapper that
  > serves the activity logs to the *frontend* (visualization pages). The
  > tracking script currently records active window titles (at frequency of
  > once every 2 seconds) and keystroke typing frequency.

  https://karpathy.github.io/2014/08/03/quantifying-productivity/
- https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch

  > The goal of ActivityWatch is simple: *Enable the collection of as much
  > valuable lifedata as possible without compromising user privacy.*
  >
  > We've worked towards this goal by creating a application for safe storage
  > of the data on the users local machine and as well as a set of watchers
  > which record data such as:
  >
  > - Currently active application and the title of its window
  > - Currently active browser tab and it's title and URL
  > - Keyboard and mouse activity, to detect if you are AFK ("away from
  >   keyboard") or not
  >
  > It is up to you as user to collect as much as you want, or as little as you
  > want (and we hope some of you will help write watchers so we can collect
  > more).
- https://github.com/selfspy/selfspy

  > Selfspy is a daemon for Unix/X11, (thanks to @ljos!) Mac OS X and (thanks
  > to @Foxboron) Windows, that continuously monitors and stores what you are
  > doing on your computer. This way, you can get all sorts of nifty statistics
  > and reminders on what you have been up to.

Related questions (automatic tracking):

- [Is there software which time- tracks window & application usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779873/is-there-software-which-time-tracks-window-application-usage)
- [TimeTracker app that logs programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93933/timetracker-app-that-logs-programs)
- [How to stay productive? What time management software is available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7273/how-to-stay-productive-what-time-management-software-is-available)
- [how can we track user activity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694080/how-can-we-track-user-activity)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465016/how-do-i-get-the-active-window-on-gnome-wayland
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139542/how-to-measure-that-how-much-time-is-the-active-window-opened
- https://web.archive.org/web/20150826143403/http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/3803/time-tracking-software-to-measure-when-im-active-or-idle-on-my-computer-i-e
- https://web.archive.org/web/20151104075656/http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/13913/automatic-time-tracking-software-for-computer-work-for-windows-linux-mac

Related questions (manual tracking):

- [Which Time Tracker application do you recommend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4113/which-time-tracker-application-do-you-recommend)